# angular ajax call with post and data using CORS is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

I Am calling restful java service with json as input and output, Which is allowing CORS calls

i have issue in sending parameters in json format

get is working fine,post without parameters is also working fine,but post with some data(payload) as key value is not working

dont know  whats the issue,tried sending data in many forms but still no luck,is the issue with  ajax call or service file or any issue with the port numbers or browsers?or any configuration issue?

here is the sample java service code:

```
@Path("/getNotes")
        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getStates(Countries countries) {

        logger.info("In UserRegistration Controller");
        return Response.status(200).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,OPTIONS")
                .entity(userService.getStates(countries.getCountryId()))
                .build();

    }
```

and js code:

```
callLocal: function (callback) {
                alert("in function");

               // $http.post('http://domain//server/rest/dashboard/Notes')//post with out any data //working fine giving output and output format is jsu a string not in json
                var payload = {"noteId": 251};
                $http({method: "POST",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    url: "  http://domain/server/rest/register/getnotes",
                   dataType: 'json',
                    //contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    //processData: true,
                    // data: JSON.stringify({"noteId": 251}),
                    data: {"noteId": 251},
                    //data: $.param({"noteId": 251}),
                    //data: $.param(payload),
//                    headers: {
//                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
//        }
                   // headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                    //   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    //  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
                    //  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,OPTIONS")
headers: {
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
                })
                       .success(function (data) {
                            alert("S");
                            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            callback(data);
                        })
                        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            alert("No data json"+status);
                            console.log(status);
                        });

            }
```

status response is :0 and console error is

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain/server/rest/register/getnoteId. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.domain.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: did you define CORS filter on your server side ? there are a couple of ways to do it depends on your project architecture

Comment: defining in server side,you mean in any htaccess file or in any other file ..as of now it is placed in service file and dont know much about how it depends on project architecture

Comment: if you are using jersey for writing web service resources you can define a filter class to handle CORS support, if you are using maven you can fetch libraries that handle CORS for you

Comment: @svarog,java developers used spring MVC to write the services

Comment: they also should have wrote a filter class that should have handled what kind or requests are permitted or not from the server. There is a Spring tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ on how that should be achieved.

Comment: @user4022479 Check in your developer console if your request gets preflighted also check if the OPTIONS method is allowed on your back end. The webservice you're trying to CORS against should have set an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Perhaps you just can't CORS from your localhost. If OPTIONS is denied, send your payload as formencoded making it a simple request which Chrome or any other browser won't preflight with an OPTIONS request.

Comment: @limelights Thanks for the reply , i will make the required changes,testing the CORS call by keeping the dump in local as well as in server,need to see if it works after implementing the changes